# why i have to hold caps-lock+shift together to enable capitalized typing in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

In order to type upper case in terminal, I have to hold caps_lock+shift together which is very upset. I have tried to change the keyboard layout in **settings > region&language>input source**,but it seems no one is suitable.

Comment: if there is a keyboard layout  suitable, please recommend it to me. I will really appreciate it

Comment: i find that i can type lower case when hold shift and after releasing it, I type upper case

Comment: What heppens when you type without holding any modifier key (no SHIFT ot CAPS)? Pres ad release CAPS, and typing, what then? Holding down SHIFT and typing ?

Comment: yes.without any key holding, i will type upper case,if i want to type lower case,i have to hold shift (left).there is no any effect after press and release CAPS .

Comment: Pressing and release CAPS should change the behavior of your keyboard to "normal" lower case pr default and CAPITAL with shift. Don't the keyboard have a caps ligt that toggles on and off when pressing CAPS? If this doesn't work your keyboard (or at least the CAPS key) might be broken.

Comment: no no. my keyboard works fine on my win10,but not on my ubuntu. My situation can almost be dealt with in the following answer even thought not the best answer(cry face).I will have to avoiding pressing the caps_lock key.That is funny@SorenA

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find...

1. The first time I log into the terminal(*reload computer rather than close the terminal and open again*), I can type lower case, if I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, then the case will turn upper.
2. If I press the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, then the situation will turn around which means that I will type upper case without holding any keys and have to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in order to type lower case
3. There ever exited a situation that if i pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, I could change the situation, but only one times.

It worked.